# Domain suffix being added to form submission

Tags: php, html, forms, contacts

I have created a really basic contact form for a website, but I'm having trouble with the 'name' field. When the mailbox receives an email the email sender is listed as $name + [Sever domain suffix]. I don't understand why the domain suffix is being added.

For instance the email sender is received as YOURNAME@prohost.17.com (This happens to be my hosts domain).

Below is the HTML and PHP used.

```
        <form action="send.php" method="post">
        <input type="text" class="conform" name="name" value="Your Name">
        <br>
        <input type="text" class="conform" name="phone" value="Contact Number">
        <br>
        <input type="email" class="conform" name="email" value="E-Mail Address">
        <br>
        <textarea class="context" name="message" cols="1" rows="10"></textarea>

        <input name="submit" type="submit" class="conbut" value="Send It">

        </form>
```

and the PHP is:

```
<?php 

$name = $_REQUEST['name'] ;
$phone = $_REQUEST['phone'] ;
$email = $_REQUEST['email'] ;
$message = $_REQUEST['message'] ;

$content = " Name: $name \n Phone: $phone \n Email: $email \n\n $message " ;

mail( "myemail@hotmail.com", "Message from mywebsite.co.uk",
    $content, "From: $name" ) ;

    header ( "Location:/success.html" ) ;

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `From` header takes an email address. You aren't giving it a full one, so it looks like either PHP or your SMTP server is resolving it from a local email address (with no `@foo` part) into one that can be used on the WWW.

Comment: thanks. I have simply used "From: $email" now to put use the sender's email when the email is received at the mailbox.

If I wanted to use the name only how could this be achieved? Do I use another instance instead of 'from' in the same location in the script?